# Treasures from the OEIS Plot 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, soft-question, analytic-number-theory, oeis

[The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/) provide us a tool with the link [**Plot 2**](https://oeis.org/plot2.html). With this tool one can perform comparisons between two different sequences of positive integers.

In number theory seems that there are some remarkable questions when one works with a sequence $A(n)$ of positive integers: defining and studying its   arithmetic mean and as a consequence the average order of $A(n)$; the order or magnitude of $A(n)$, or some *notion of density* for the terms of our sequence $A(n)$ (for example defining an asymptotic density, or well studying how fast goes to infinite  $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}$ versus $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$, more examples with primes or different sequences of positive integers are well known). Also as an aside aslo if the terms of our sequence of positive integers satisfy remarkable congruences, recurrences or diophantine equations.

> **Question.** I would like to know if comparing a well known sequence of positive integers $A(n)$ with a little-known sequence of positive integers $\hat{A}(n)$ you can tranfer some remarkable knowledges from $A(n)$ to $\hat{A}(n)$ using this tool **Plot 2**. Is it feasible? If yes, how does work your example? That is, how do you explore a little-known sequence $hat{A}(n)$ from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences using Plot 2 by means of a comparison with a well known $A(n)$? **Thanks in advance.**

Only are required didactic tips, but if for your example you can set good statements or conjectures using this tool Plot 2, it  is appreciated. In your example feel free to change your input $A(n)$ to make multiple comparisons but always for a same $\hat{A}(n)$.

Comment: If this question is useful as a reference in the future, feel free to improve the grammar. Many thanks.

Comment: Many thanks @ParclyTaxel

Comment: This is a "soft" question. I'm sure the answer is "yes": using various tools (including OEIS' "plot 2"), you can find remarkable and fascinating coincidences (or even meaningful connections) between sequences. However, I don't know if there's a good "automated" or even "semi-automated" way to do this. If there were, I'm guessing someone would've used it.

Comment: Following your words I've added the tag (soft-question) with the purpose to draw the attention of more users and their reasonings. Many thanks @barrycarter